# LINQ Problem takes all from list not the ones i want

Tags: c#, linq

Hey so im still working on my project and i ran into another problem,
its kinda hard to explain but i think my LINQ might just be wrong:

```
        private async void AddTasks()
        {
            List<string> folders = new List<string>();
            List<TaskStruct> allTasks = await taskApi.GetTasks();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
            foreach (TaskStruct task in allTasks)
            {
                if (folders.Contains(task.folder) == false)
                {
                    folders.Add(task.folder);
                    var newFolder = new TaskFolderView(this, task.folder, allTasks.Where(task => task.folder.Equals(task.folder)).ToList());
                    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(newFolder);
                }
            }
        }
```

I think the problem is on:

```
var newFolder = new TaskFolderView(this, task.folder, allTasks.Where(task => task.folder.Equals(task.folder)).ToList());
```

I get allTasks in the view like this but i only want the ones that match with the foldername.
Hope someone can help

Comment: The problem is the Loop variable and the LINQ variable both has the same name `task`

Comment: `task.folder.Equals(task.folder)` is always true. Perhaps not what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used the same variable name twice. You use it once here:

```cs
foreach (TaskStruct task in allTasks)
```

and again here:

```cs
Where(task =>
```

Look at the condition in your `Where` call:

```cs
task.folder.Equals(task.folder)
```

Why would you think that you could use `task.folder` twice in the same expression and have it mean two different things? Both of those are referring to the inner `task` variable so you're just equating one thing with itself, which is always `true`, which is why every item matches.

This is an example of why I always use type initials for LINQ range variables in this context. They will never clash with other variables and the scope is so small that there's never a risk of their being confusing. You can do this:

```cs
Where(t => t.folder.Equals(task.folder))
```

and now you're actually equating two different things.